# Is there a way to add Interface Builder options to a custom class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

In my app, I made a subclass of UIView that I want to use in Interface Builder. Is there a way to make the instance variables settable via the "Attributes" section of IB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but not easily. In order for any custom controls to have Interface Builder support, you'll need to develop an IB plugin. I recommend going to the source for the nitty gritty. Take a look at the [Interface Builder Plugin Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004323). Or, for a less overwhelming source, [this blog](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/custom-views-in-interface-builder-using.html).

Comment: So basically it's not worth it unless I'll be using it on a large scale?